# RSA: least significant bit position in key

Tags: encryption, rsa, keys, decryption

How can I show that $C' = 2^e·C^* \bmod N$ when it is decrypted will add zero bits in the least significant bit position of the key?

I am not sure if the cause is multiplying by a ciphertext which would lead the key to be multiplied by it as well.

Comment: Welcome to CSE, and kudos for now using MathJax (is not that wonderful?). What does the star in $C^*$ mean? Note: there might be some confusion about least significant bit position in _key_, when as far as I can see only least significant bit position in _plaintext_ gets changed.

Comment: @fgrieu thank you. I'm asking for the least significant bit position of the key not the ciphertext. for C* it denotes that it is different than C'

Comment: In (textbook/unpadded) RSA, when modified ciphertext $C'$ gets decrypted, we get a mofied _plaintext_. We do not get any new _key_ or key component, thus the ciphertext modification can not "add zero bits in the least significant bit position of the key". There is all signs that you are asking for the least significant bit position of the _plaintext_, not _key_ or _ciphertext_. And that's the [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76378/555) you got.

Comment: @fgrieu I think the key is actually the cipher text ( if the OP sends a key via RSA, as is common).

Answer (score 1):

Because (if $C=P^e$ where $P$ is the plain text): $2^e C= (2P)^c \pmod{N}$ so multiplying the ciphertext by $2^e$ modifies the plain text by a multiplication of $2$, which is a bitshift to the left of $1$, so we get 1 new zero bit at the end. To get $m$ zero bits, we need to multiply by $2^{em}$ (modulo $N$), of course.

Comment: but I'm actually trying to figure it out for the key not the ciphertext. How is that possible?